# svelte:component with DOM elements

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

### Goal

I'm creating a button component in Svelte that will either render as `<button>` or `<a>` element, depending on whether it's a link or not. Is it possible to use `svelte:component`?

Something like this…

```
<script lang='ts'>
  export let href: string = ''

  $: component = href ? a : button // where "a" and "button" are the HTML DOM elements
</script>

<svelte:component this={component}>
 <slot></slot>
</svelte:component>
```

So far, I've only seen examples of `svelte:component` rendering custom Svelte components, not DOM elements

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component

[How to dynamically render components in Svelte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656481/how-to-dynamically-render-components-in-svelte)

### Motivation

It is possible to use if/else to get the desired results…

```
<script lang='ts'>
  export let href: string = ''
</script>

{# if href}
  <a {href}>
    <slot></slot>
  </a>
{:else}
  <button>
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
{/if}
```

…but this is not maintainable.

- The entire contents is duplicated. In the simple example above, the contents is just the children. In reality, there are multiple slots for (e.g, prefixes/suffixes), leading to lots of duplicated logic.
- I can see uses for this design pattern in many other components with more than 2 variants (e.g., a `Container` component that can be a `div`, `section`, `article`, `aside`, etc.). More variants results in an even messier code structure.

### React equivalent

Here's an example React component with the desired functionality.

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const Tag = props.href ? 'a' : 'button'

  return <Tag href={props.href}>{contents}</Tag>
}
```

### Solutions I wish to avoid

#### 1. The if/else pattern

Same pattern as above.

#### 2. Creating a "children" component

Instead of duplicating the children multiple times, you could move it into its own component and just import the child into the if/else chain. At least then there won't be duplicated logic, but the props/slots will need to be duplicated.

```
<script lang='ts'>
  import Children from './children.svelte'

  export let href: string = ''
</script>

{# if href}
  <a {href}>
    <Children><slot></slot></Children>
  </a>
{:else}
  <button>
    <Children><slot></slot></Children>
  </button>
{/if}
```

#### 3. Create wrapper components

For every wrapper DOM element, just create a new Svelte component. Then, import those as actual Svelte components and use `svelte:component`

```
<!-- dom-a.svelte -->

<a {...$$props}><slot></slot></a>
```

```
<!-- dom-button.svelte -->

<button {...$$props}><slot></slot></button>
```

```
<!-- button.svelte -->
<script lang='ts'>
  import A from './dom-a.svelte'
  import Button from './dom-button.svelte'

  export let href: string = ''

  $: component = href ? A : Button
</script>

<svelte:component this={component}>
 <slot></slot>
</svelte:component>
```

While this is the nicest to use as a developer, there is a [performance penalty](https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props) for having unknown props. Therefore, it's not idea.

I suppose you could specify every single possible prop in the `dom-button.svelte` and `dom-a.svelte` components, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>It is not possible to use `<svelte:component>` for this. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2324) to add a new `<svelte:element>` tag for this functionality, but it **has not been implemented yet**. There is an [open PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/5481) to add this tag to Svelte.</s>

EDIT: this is now possible in Svelte 3.47.0 with [svelte:element](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-element). You can now do the following:

```svelte
<script>
    export let href = '';
    
    let tag = href ? 'a' : 'button';
</script>

<svelte:element this={tag} {href}>
    <slot></slot>
</svelte:element>
```